# normalizeResponse not recognizing link between nested relationships

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

The API endpoint I'm working with is returning data that has multiple nested relationships inside it, and I am using `normalizeResponse()` within `DS.JSONAPISerializer` to massage it into something that is fully JSON-API compliant.

The ember inspector shows that all data gets placed within its respective container correctly. The link between the top-level model and its `hasMany` child does work, but the link between the nested models does not work.  I verify this by navigating within the inspector to the nested model's child model, clicking on it, and observing that its 'content' property is null.

First, take a look at how my models are set up:

```
// models/search.js
// i am able to browse from the search model to children with success
export default DS.Model.extend({
  articles: DS.hasMany('article'),
});

// models/article.js
// i CANNOT browse from an article down to its digest in ember inspector
export default DS.Model.extend({
  search: DS.belongsTo('search'),
  type: DS.attr(),
  created: DS.attr(),
  updated: DS.attr(),
  digest: DS.belongsTo('digest'),
});

// models/digest.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  desc: DS.attr(),
  date: DS.attr(),
  article: DS.belongsTo('article'),
});
```

Now, here's my modified JSON after my functions inside `normalizeResponse` complete.  AFTER returning this data from `normalizeResponse`, the "digest" object under the parent "relationships" object disappears.  Is there something wrong with my JSON?  I've tried so many permutations of this with no success, and I am pretty sure this matches the JSON-API spec for [Compound Documents](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents).

```
{"data":{
  "type":"searches",
  "id":"17482738723",
  "attributes":{

  },
  "relationships":{
    "articles":{
      "data":[
        {
          "type":"articles",
          "id":"19988"
        },
        {
          "type":"articles",
          "id":"19989"
        },
      ]
    },
    "digest":{
      "data":[
        {
          "type":"digest",
          "id":"19988_digest"
        },
        {
          "type":"digest",
          "id":"19989_digest"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
},
"included":[
  {
    "id":"19988",
    "type":"articles",
    "attributes":{
      "type": "internal",
      "created":"2016-09-27T00:13:11.000Z",
      "updated":"2016-09-27T00:13:11.000Z",
    }
  },
  {
    "id":"19988_digest",
    "type":"digest",
    "attributes":{
      "title":null,
      "desc":"four five six",
    }
  },
  {
    "id":"19989",
    "type":"articles",
    "attributes":{
      "type": "internal",
      "created":"2016-09-27T00:13:11.000Z",
      "updated":"2016-09-27T00:13:11.000Z",
    }
  },
  {
    "id":"19989_digest",
    "type":"digest",
    "attributes":{
      "title":"one two three",
      "desc":null,
    }
  },
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response indicates the following relationship model:

```
// models/search.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  articles: DS.hasMany('article'),
  dignists: DS.hasMany('digest'),
});

// models/article.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  search: DS.belongsTo('search'),
});

// models/digest.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  search: DS.belongsTo('search'),
});
```

So you have to fix your response:

- remove the `digest` relationship on the `search`
- add a `digest` relationship to every `article`

So you will end with something like this:

```
{
  "data":{
    "type":"searches",
    "id":"17482738723",
    "attributes":{
    },
    "relationships":{
      "articles":{
        "data":[
          {
            "type":"articles",
            "id":"19988"
          },
          {
            "type":"articles",
            "id":"19989"
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "included":[
    {
      "id":"19988",
      "type":"articles",
      "attributes":{
        "type": "internal",
        "created":"2016-09-27T00:13:11.000Z",
        "updated":"2016-09-27T00:13:11.000Z",
      },
      "relationships":{
        "digest": {
          "data": {
            "type":"digest",
            "id":"19988_digest"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id":"19988_digest",
      "type":"digest",
      "attributes":{
        "title":null,
        "desc":"four five six",
      },
      "relationships":{
        "digest":{
          "data": {
            "type":"digest",
            "id":"19989_digest"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id":"19989",
      "type":"articles",
      "attributes":{
        "type": "internal",
        "created":"2016-09-27T00:13:11.000Z",
        "updated":"2016-09-27T00:13:11.000Z",
      }
    },
    {
      "id":"19989_digest",
      "type":"digest",
      "attributes":{
        "title":"one two three",
        "desc":null,
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Know that you can also do it the other way around and specify the `article` on the `digest`. `ember-data` will automatically keep everything in sync. I personally prefer to specify both sides of the relationship for clarity.